# Export all constants from files into index.ts and then export those constants as keys of an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, constants, export

I have a constant library that has many files such as the following structure:

#1 index.ts

#2 src/

- contact.ts

  - const first = [];
  - const second = [];
  - const third = [];
- location.ts

  - const first = '';
  - const second = '';
  - const third = '';

Is it possible to import and export all of the constants from each file into `index.ts` such that I can import into a project such as the following:

```js
// Imports: Constants
import { constants } from '@jeff/constants-library';

console.log(constants.contact.first);
console.log(constants.contact.second);
console.log(constants.contact.third);
```

What is the fastest/most efficient way to dynamically export the constants from my library files so I can import the into my projects?

Answer (score 1):

In your files like `contact` and `location`, you'll need to mark the `const` values you want as `export`s. Modules are designed for encapsulation, so dynamic export isn't really an option here. However, it's just a matter of adding the keyword `export`:

```
export const first = [];
```

After that, you can create a `constants-library.ts` or `constants-library/index.ts` which automatically exports and imports:

```
import * as foo from './foo';
import * as bar from './bar';

export const constants = { foo, bar };
```

At this point, assuming your `@jeff` path is set up, your code should work as expected:

```
import { constants } from '@jeff/constants-library';

console.log(constants.contact.first);
```

Note that this will include *all* of the exports in your files, since TypeScript can't tell which constants you want or didn't want--it only knows which exports you've listed. As an alternative, rather than exporting all of your `const`s individually, you could bundle them into a single `export` using object shorthand.

```
// in contact.ts and location.ts
export constants = { first, second, third };

// in constant-library.ts or constant-library/index.ts
import { constants as contact } from './contact';
import { constants as location } from './location';

export constants = { contact, location };
```